# Is Krillin the strongest pure human in the Dragonball Z Universe?

Tags: dragon-ball

In Dragonball the series keeps increasing power levels. Most of the truly powerful characters though are aliens or only part human. Usually in a fight all of the Z Warriors are taken down at some point but it always seems like Krillin is able to fight longer than any of the other humans. So is he the strongest actual human currently on Earth in the Dragonball Z Universe?

Comment: Edit you question to the actual series.

Comment: I meant the Dragonball series over all (not the video games though) I'm not familiar enough and get confused by the differentiations between the series titles ( this hasn't been helped by my friends who throw out multiple references to manga, japan series and english) so I thought putting Dragonball series would be enough.

Comment: Mr. Satan is the strongest human, hahahahaha

Comment: I don't think Krillin can be considered a pure human, he was lacking his nose, so might have been mutated or different anyway. Yamcha could have been considered a pure human

Comment: I don't know if Krillin is the strongest human, but one thing is sure: he has the most weird hair regenerating capabilities among humans!!

Comment: I have to ask - genetically speaking, isn't Goku human? If he produces offspring with a human that can then produce offspring, he's the same species... right? Human. Or is this explained some other way? In addition, I don't remember saiyans ever being explicitly labeled as a different species, so perhaps it's akin to saying saiyans are like Africans or Asians or Polynesian - one of their particular adaptations just happens to be a tail and certain semi-involuntary trance-like transformations

Comment: In universe: 1. Uub. 2. Olibu. 3. Krillin. But in both DBZ and DBS, Olibu is already dead and Uub is not yet born or still a baby, leaving to Krillin to be the strongest pure human. Note that Krillin is stronger than Videl or Master Roshi. And C18 and Tien Shinhan aren't pure humans.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

No, [Uub](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Uub#Power), the reincarnation of [Buu](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Kid_Buu) is more powerful than Krillin.

> As the reincarnation of Kid Buu, who fought evenly against and ultimately outlasted Super Saiyan 3 Goku without any signs of fatigue, **Uub is considered the strongest human character in the series.**

[image]

Comment: This is the correct answer, and to further that, unlike the *forms* of Buu, Uub is in fact a pure human, regardless of the fact that he is the reincarnation of Buu.

Comment: Its not the correct answer because Uub isn't the most powerful in the Z or ball series because he wasn't trained.  He is the strongest living human in GT.  Uub (end of Z series) had no practice or skill, so Uub wouldn't be the strongest.  He would only have the most potential.

Comment: @Blue I was seeking the strongest pure human in the whole Dragonball serie.

Comment: The questions asks for DragonBall Z series or DragonBall series.  The questioner hasn't clarified series.

Comment: @Blue That's a bit short sighted. At the end of Z Goku *was* training with him, and practice showed that he was nearly even with Goku. Also, why would he have to be "trained" in order to be powerful. He started with a lot of in-built power, before Goku went to meet him.

Comment: @Gorchestopher H Gohan Vs Raditz.  Uub was as strong as Goku normal form which isn't even close 2 ssj3.  While Android 18 can go on ssj2.  An example between fighting Uub(untrained) and a trained martial artist like Piccolo or someone.  Gohan still lost to Raditz.

Comment: @Blue The questions says "strongest" not "most battle experienced". He was born with the power of Buu. He fights Goku in a DBZ episode in the tournament, clearly with power greater than any other human.

Comment: Locked potential doesn't mean the person is the strongest because you can't manifest the strength.

Comment: from the wiki. It is revealed here by Goku that Uub is actually the reincarnated Human form of Kid Buu, who was born from the wish made by Goku just before he defeated Buu with the Super Spirit Bomb.   I could not find anything on what the wish Goku made was. I think this will clarify if Uub is a pure human.

Comment: King Yemma reincarnated Buu to Uub.  Also, the Strongest fighter would be the Strongest in battle, not just in strength.

Comment: As long as we're talking about people stronger than Krillin, would Master Roshi count?

Comment: @KevinHowell Indeed Uub is pure human, born into a remote human tribe. Goku's "wish" is only hinted at when Goku tells the group about Uub by saying that Yemma must have heard his wish.

Comment: One extra item to mention here, if it helps define Uub's humanity. In the final episode of DBZ it is revealed that Uub has 4 younger siblings and spends his days working with his father to support his family. At the beginning of his match with Goku, Bulma states "it's a shame he came all this way to face Goku first", Dende then mentions to Piccolo in an aside "this will be the real championship match" to which Piccolo agrees. At the end of the match Goku tells Uub that he is very strong, but needs to learn how to harness his strength.

Answer (score 9):

**Krillin was the strongest human in Dragonball but not in Dragonball Z.**  The difference between the two periods is one is when Goku was a kid, and the other was when he found out he was a Saiyan, etc.

During the Underworld tournament, held by Grand Kai,there was one human, [Olibu](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Olibu), who reached the finals of the previous Underworld tournament.

[image: Olibu]

In conclusion,  Olibu was the strongest human fighter on Earth.

Dragonball series:  Strongest living human was Krillin

DragonBall Z: Strongest Living Human was Krillin; Strongest Human was Olibu;
              Strongest Initial Human was Android 18

DragonBall GT: Strongest Human was Uub

Comment: Good point I clarified to mean on Earth currently. Also I didn't think that Android 18 counted as human since she is an android.

Comment: Android 18 counts because she originally human then was modified by Dr. Gero, then was wished to be human again with the dragonballs.

Comment: @Blue but then Android 18 is not "Pure".

Comment: @DavRob60 she was wished Pure.

Comment: http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Android_18 according to this that wish couldn't be granted. And she not a pure human.

Comment: Yamcha kicked the crap out of Olibu.
And 18 was never wished back to being a full human.

Comment: Oh and to edit your answer of video, Krillin was trained by master Roshi and he also is a gifted human fighter. Just like goku is a gifted saiyen. Stronger than most saiyens including vageta in certain timelines of the series.

Comment: I know this is a really old question, but: As far as I know, Olibu wasn't considered canon by most because he was anime filler. Also, was Krillin ever confirmed stronger than Tien as of the end of Dragon Ball?

Answer (score 0):

Uub is the recreation of Buu because of the dragon balls so he can't be considered fully human. I dont understand Krillin because Videl has been training her whole life and can only fly.

Answer (score 0):

Krillin is the strongest because in the Cell story arc he flys in and kicks Cell right in the face. Plus, Krillin's power level is far beyond any human's power level. He gained all his strength through training and hard work. Anyone else pales in comparison to Krillin's extreme work ethic. Krillin wasn't wished strong by some Dragonball bologna. He became strong by working out. May all of us learn a lesson from this.

Answer (score 0):

Krill is the strongest human in the dragon ball Z universe I think he had a power level stronger than freeza correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Is there anything in the story line to support this?

Answer (score 0):

Since the Inclusion of Dragon Ball Super Uub is no longer Canon, unless he appears again on the new manga.

Dragon Ball GT is not Canon also.

Using Current Cannon Only, and also humans currently alive.

In The Dragon Ball Movie Frieza Resurection whe see 2 pure humans fighting against frieza henchmen. Tenchinham and Krillin. Tenchinham has never stopped training in his life. While Krillin in fact took some breaks from it. He has a family now.

I will say that Tenchinham is stronger than Krillin.

Tenchinham was able to fight againts cell second form for a little bit of time.

Krillin didnt even try.

Krillin might seem stronger, since he has seen more screen time than Tenchinham, but if both of them had to fight each other, Tenchinham extra eye plus dedication would be Krillins Downfall.

Comment: Wrong. Uub and the tournament he participates in is canon. Only GT and games other than DBXV/DBO are not canon. The added canon makes him even more powerful, but Krillin and the other Humans are supposed to become more relevant in DBS meaning that Uub is that much more powerful and is the strongest Human as far as canon is concerned until it is revealed otherwise in DBS if it at all is.

Answer (score -1):

Krillin is the strongest human obviously; Akira Toriyama, creator of db, dbz, dbgt, etc.  has stated this multiple times in the series.  He posses the strongest attack in the series, Destructo Disk, able to kill anything. A fight with a Saiyan would've been over in less than one minute if Krillin had thought of it sooner. But then again where would be the suspense of the fight? Goku is the main character anyways so they gave him most of the credit. (A little too much in my opinion)

Comment: I edited this answer to correct some spelling and grammar mistakes, but I would add some citations of Toriyama stating Krillin as the strongest to back up your claim.

Answer (score -1):

yes krillin is the strongest human ever, tien shinhan comes close to krillins power but krillins is still greater, the only pure human that was ever stronger then krillin was uub, after he was trained by goku in dragonball gt. but then when ubb he was fighting baby in dragonball gt he was about to die so majin buu (fat buu) fused with ubb and then he was known as majuub. after that he was no longer a pure human so krillin once again became the strongest pure human ever in the dragonball z universe.

Comment: Tien Shinhan is a descendant from the Three-Eyed People, making him a non-pure human.